# Martingale constructed from a random walk

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, markov-process, random-walk

I am trying to solve this problem for a while now but I am not coming to a solution. Could anyone help or give me a hint?

> Let $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i$ be a random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$ with $S_0=0$, $\mathbb{P}(X_i=1)=\frac{2}{3}$,  $\mathbb{P}(X_i=-1)=\frac{1}{3}$. For which strictly positive constant $c\neq1$ is $M_n:= c^{S_n}$ a martingale?

Comment: $M_{n+1}=M_n c^{X_{n+1}}$ so I reckon $c^{X_{n+1}}$ should have expectation $1$.

Comment: @AnginaSeng What I was thinking is that $\mathbb{P}(c^{X_{n+1}}=1)=1$? Also from some other calculation I get $\mathbb{E}(c^{X_{n+1}} | F_n )=1$, where $F_n$ is the natural filtration. But I don't know how to work further with this.

Comment: @AnginaSeng how does one see that $c^{X_{n+1}}$ needs to have expectation 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you get it. So, note that
$$
E(c^{S_{n+1}}\mid \mathcal F_n) = E(c^{S_n}\cdot c^{X_{n+1}} \mid  \mathcal F_n)= c^{S_n} E(c^{X_{n+1}})=
c^{S_{n}}
$$

Therefore, you need that $E(c^{X_{n+1}})=1$. Hence,

$$
E(c^{X_{n+1}})= c2/3+1/(3c)= 1
$$

Solve the above equation and find $c$.